# Program to send mail won't compile

Tags: windows, perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::SMTP;

# to install Net::SMTP moudle package, run cpan command in command line
# in the shell type install Net::SMTP

sub send_mail
####################################################################################################
#
# SUBROUTINE : send_mail
#
# PURPOSE    : Send an email.
#
# INPUT(S)   : smtp_server - Simple Mail Transfer Protocol server
#              to          - Recipient address
#              from        - Sender address
#              subject     - Subject
#              body        - Reference to an array containing the message body
#
# OUTPUT(S)  : 0 - success
#              1 - failure
#
####################################################################################################
{


     my $from    = 'home.yosef@gmail.com';
     my $to      = 'home.yosef@gmail.com';
     my $data    = "A simple test message from Perl script\n";
     my $subject = "Hello World from Perl script";

     smtp_server => "smtp.gmail.com";



    # Connect to the SMTP server
    my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new($smtp_server);

    # If connection is successful, send mail
    if ($smtp) {

        # Establish to/from
        $smtp->mail($from);
        $smtp->to($to);

        # Start data transfer
        $smtp->data();

        # Send the header
        $smtp->datasend("To: $to\n");
        $smtp->datasend("From: $from\n");
        $smtp->datasend("Subject: $subject\n");
        $smtp->datasend("\n");

        # Send the body
        $smtp->datasend(@body);

        # End data transfer
        $smtp->dataend();

        # Close the SMTP connection
        $smtp->quit();

    # If connection fails return with error
    }
    else {

        # Print warning
        warn "WARNING: Failed to connect to $smtp_server: $!";

        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

# Define the message body
my @message_body = "Hello World! from Perl script\n";
push @message_body, "Add another line!\n";

# Send the email!
send_mail(
    smtp_server => <smtp_server_name>,
    to          => <to_address>,
    from        => <from_address>,
    subject     => 'This is a mail from Perl script',
    body        => \@message_body,
);
```

I have Windows installed with Strawberry Perl. When I run this script from the command line I get errors and I donn't know what is wrong.

These are the errors:

> Global symbol "$smtp_server" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $smtp_server"?) at windows_send_mail_with_SMTP.pl line 40.
>   Global symbol "@body" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @body"?) at windows_send_mail_with_SMTP.pl line 59.
>   Global symbol "$smtp_server" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $smtp_server"?) at windows_send_mail_with_SMTP.pl line 71.
>   Execution of windows_send_mail_with_SMTP.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: For one, you're missing the scalar sigil (`$`) at the beginning of this statement: `smtp_server => "smtp.gmail.com";`. Change it to `my $smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com";`. There may be other issues, but that's a glaring one.

Comment: @stevieb: You have a glaring error in your  "fix"; perhaps even two!

Comment: @Borodin not enough coffee yet ;)

Comment: You have made the all-too-common mistake of writing way too much code before you tried running it. You've even written a big fancy comment block which does nothing to help you to write the code. It's not like building a petrol engine, where you have to pretty much finish the job before you can try it. Programs can be compiled and run well before they are complete, and you should write only a few lines between tests. That way you can be certain where any error lies, and can fix it swiftly. You can also avoid writing large amounts of code based on a false premise, and having to delete it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think it's pretty clear from the messages. You haven't declared (or defined) either `$smtp_server` or `@body`

This line doesn't do anything useful

```
smtp_server => "smtp.gmail.com"
```

The `=>` operator is just a comma that happens to put quotes around its first parameter, so it's the same as

```
"smtp_server", "smtp.gmail.com"
```

which just evaluates two strings and discards them

Since you have already successfully defined four other variables on the lines before, I don't understand why you chose to do something different here

As for `@body`, you never declare it or put anything into it. As the error message says,

> did you forget to declare "my @body"?